# Parse crash report not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash, parse-platform

I'm trying to use Parse new crash reporting API in my application.
I've linked all libraries to my project, created bridging headers to make it work with Swift and added this code to AppDelegate:

```
// Enable Crash Reporting
ParseCrashReporting.enable();

// Setup Parse
Parse.setApplicationId("parseAppId", clientKey:"parseClientKey")
```

My app crashed many times since than, but still no crash reports showed up. I tried it in emulator as well as on physical device. Other Parse functions are working without problem, so it's not problem with wrong appID and stuff like that.

Comment: Please contact their support.

Answer (score 0):

A few points on Parse crash reporting.

1. You don't need to add bridging header as Parse has Swift SDK now.
2. In Parse starter project include `ParseCrashReporing.framework`
3. Crash reports are shown in dashboard after some time.
4. Try to test on device rather than simulator.
5. Crash report is submitted on relaunch of app, once it has been crashed.